# Scipy/numpy how to compute function as vector?

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, differential-equations

I am trying to use `solve_bvp` from scipy. To that effect I need to create the RHS function, which on paper I ahve as

`(1+y^2) / 2(1-x)`

I am not sure how to define the function that takes the vecotrs as inputs and rewrite it for my case.

I.e. I am trying to rewrite the function `fun_measles` [in this tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html) into my function.

```
mu = 0.02
l = 0.0279
eta = 0.01
def fun_measles(x, y):
    beta = 1575 * (1 + np.cos(2 * np.pi * x))
    return np.vstack((
        mu - beta * y[0] * y[2],
        beta * y[0] * y[2] - y[1] / l,
        y[1] / l - y[2] / eta
    ))
```

Comment: When using functions like `solve_bvp` read the docs carefully. Pay close attention to kind of `func` it accepts - the inputs the function should accept (ie. how`solve_bvp` will call it), and what `solve_bvp` expects in return.  Functions like this are quite picky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `y[1] / l - y[2] / eta` computes a scalar rather than a vector. Hence, when `np.vstack` is called, it fails to execute because dimensions of the input don't match.

You fix the formula (this line) and you will be able to vectorize the function.

Comment: I am confused, you seem to be answering something different than what I was asking. My issue is not compiling that function. THat function comes from the tutorial, I need to rewrite it to express my problem isntead of the tutorials.

Comment: This is wrong. The input by solve_bvp is given as tuple of lists of samples (not as list of state vectors), so `y[1]` is the list of samples of the second component for the list `x` of sample points.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can just implement it the same as the scalar case. You only need to take care when you use operations that are different between scalar and vector cases, such as branching based on the `y` value, where in the array case you need to use the numpy functions such as `p.where`.

One has to care about the shape of the return array. So it is either

```
return (1+y**2) / (2*(1-x))
```

or

```
return [ (1+y[0]**2) / (2*(1-x)) ]
```

(I'm not sure if explicit numpy-ification is really helpful, the solver will do that correctly anyway, so it is only the question of where the overhead happens.)